How to pass authentication required check if downloading Zip file form JFROG Artifactory
I am using this command in workflow file
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ${{ env.Some_URL }} -OutFile file.zip

and in environment variable i am setting this
  ARTIFACTORY_JFROGHUBVWGROUPCOM_USR: ${{ secrets.ARTIFACTORY_USER }}
  ARTIFACTORY_JFROGHUBVWGROUPCOM_PSW: ${{ secrets.ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY }}
  Some_URL: "https://${{ secrets.ARTIFACTORY_USER }}:${{ secrets.ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY }}@jfrog.hub.vwgroup.com/artifactory/some.zip"


Now when i execute the workflow it is saying Authentication is required (PFA)
error message in runner
NOTE: I am using windows as runner and if this user doesn't have access then error message will different for sure.
I am expecting that zip file should be downloaded, because it does have username and api with it in JFROG link

Instead of embedding the credentials in the URL, did you try passing them using the -Credential parameter? E.g: Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Some_URL -OutFile file.zip -Credential $Credential

same error message :(

You are using an API Key. The easiest way is to pass it in a header:
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ${{ env.Some_URL }} -OutFile file.zip -Headers @{ "APIKey" = "AKC...WP"}

See Help Centre

still error message saying authentication is required :(

Please try this with curl or wget locally to make sure the URL and the API key are correct

Locally I cannot test it, because

User and API Key is different (Tech User in CI/CD)
To me i don't have access, only Tech user in CI/CD have.

only way to access the credentials of tech user is secrets, as you can see in env. variables
